# Duplicate MovieClip in AIR/AS3

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, air

Has anyone noticed how creating new instances of a MovieClip (and likely other objects as well) in AIR causes some strange effects? If you use [Senocular's method](http://www.senocular.com/flash/actionscript.php?file=ActionScript_3.0/com/senocular/display/duplicateDisplayObject.as) by grabbing the object constructor and creating a new instance of the MovieClip, you end up with a new MovieClip with 0 frames. I don't want to draw bitmapData's of every frame into an array, does anyone have a suggestion for making a real duplicate of a MovieClip? (i.e. not just a strong reference).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i'd personally use flash.utils:

```
getQualifiedClassName(value:*):String
```

and

```
getDefinitionByName(name:String):Object
```

And create an instance using the Class object

I'm sure there may be a reason why Senocular has used this method, but it may be worth trying replacing that line using these two methods to see if it solves any issues you are having.

Comment: Hmm, that may work since that would eliminate the need to convert a MovieClip to an Object first. Thanks, I'll let you know how it goes.

Comment: Nope. That didn't work. I'm still getting a 1 frame Movieclip, though it did create a new one. I can verify that the MovieClip I'm trying to copy IS on stage, but nothing is drawn in to the MovieClip. Again, this seems to be in AIR only.

Answer (score 0):

I second, any approach involving getDefinition/getDefinitionByName/object contructor trick does not work inside Adobe AIR (3.7, possibly others).

```
var movieClipShallow : MovieClip = loader.getMovieClip(url);
var constructor: Class = (movieClipShallow as Object).constructor;
var anotherInstance: MovieClip = new constructor();
```

movieClipShallow contains different width/height/numFrames/etc. than anotherInstance

I currently do not have solution for that :(